# Bounds on reducing from NP to SAT

Tags: computational-complexity

Let M be a non deterministic turing machine.

Suppose M is a TM that runs in T(n) time.

Given an instance of x in {0,1}^n, and the question M(x) accepts?

We can

1) convert M into an oblivious TM that runs in O( T \log T) time.
2) convert the oblivious TM into a circuit SAT instance with O( T \log T ) gates.
3) Convert the circuit SAT into a 3CNF with O (T \log T) vars and O (T \log T) clauses.

Question: is there a way to make this tighter? In particular, can I get a SAT instance of vars/clauses O(n), rather than O( T(n) \log T(n) ) ?

Or is this essentially impossible, as I am forced to have a variable for each non-deterministic step the TM takes, (thus lower bounded to T(n)).

Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible because it would contradict the nondeterministic time hierarchy theorem.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem#Non-deterministic_time_hierarchy_theorem

Comment: note: there is a meta-discussion about the recent questions in complexity including this one [here](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1164/recent-questions-in-complexity-theory/).

Comment: My previous comment is wrong, because the time complexity of the reduction can be any polynomial depending on the language.